# How do I set the height of a wpf slider control's thumb 

Tags: wpf, slider

I want to put a slider in a datagrid cell and the row has a height of 20, so i'd like to make the height of the thumb of the slider smaller than that. I set the height of the slider itself, but the thumb appears to be cut off (i.e. it doesn't scale down to the height that I specify in the slider.height property). I don't want to have to override the entire control template of the slider control to do this. There's got to be some way of setting a property or something like that.

Edit: Even when I create a custom slider style which includes the custom thumb style with the sizes I want, it still doesn't size right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

```
<Slider.LayoutTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.9" CenterX="15" CenterY="15"/>
</Slider.LayoutTransform>
```

Not very sexy, but it works like a charm when combined whith the Slider.Height/Slider.Width properties !

Comment: Great and easy solution if the scale changes are not too large (0.6-1.4 or something like that) which would be most common.

Comment: hahahaha! Thanks! it works for UWP as well ` <Slider.RenderTransform>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.5" CenterX="0" CenterY="7"/>
                                        </Slider.RenderTransform>`

Answer (score 2):

Set thumb style:

```
<Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <!--<Ellipse 
                      Name="Ellipse" 
                      Fill="Yellow"
                      Stroke="Yellow" 
                      Height="10"
                      Width="{Binding Path=ThumbWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                      StrokeThickness="1" />-->
                <Rectangle 
                    Fill="Azure"
                    Stroke="Azure"
                    Height="7"
                    Width="{Binding Path=ThumbWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    StrokeThickness="1"
                    Margin="0.1,.1,.1,.1"/>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then use this style slider custom control

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:NvSliderControl}">
    <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>        
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:NvSliderControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" >
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}">
                                </Thumb>
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```